# ASP.NET MVC 5 application - How can I redirect to a URL after an ajax post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect the user to a page after the ajax post is successful.  The session variable does get changed, but it never redirects afterwards.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectFacility(string Facility)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Facility"] = Facility;
    return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Incident") });
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#Facility").on("change", function () {
        var fac = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        /*
        $.post("/Incident/SelectFacility", {
            Facility: fac
        });
        window.location = result.redirectUrl;*/

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SelectFacility","Incident")',
            type: 'POST',
            //contentType: 'application/json', not needed
            //dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp is for sending to a site other than the current one
            data: {
                Facility: fac
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == true) {
                    window.location = result.redirectUrl;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `redirectToUrl` and `redirectUrl` are not the same thing.

Comment: In your javascript `result.redirectUrl` you are missing a "To" `redirectToUrl` != `redirectUrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `result` will hold an object, so comparing it to `true` is rather odd (although will actually work here due to type coercion).

Secondly, and the main issue with your logic, is that you're checking the `redirectUrl` property of the response, but the correct name is `redirectToUrl`.

```js
success: function(result) {
  window.location = result.redirectToUrl;
}
```

However, it's worth noting that in this situation the AJAX request is completely redundant as you're redirecting the page immediately after it completes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I assume in youn controller you have action, after that use `location.href` 
to redirect where you action is located.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.functionName', function() {
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    type: "info",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#2196F3",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, assign it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  }, function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "User/Create",
      ajaxasync: true,
      success: function() {
        swal("Assigned!", "User has been created!", "success");
        location.href = "/User/Create";
      },
      error: function(data) {
        swal("Oops", "Something went wrong!", "error");
      }
    });
```

Comment: The OP is returning the URL from the AJAX request, not hard-coding it. Also, why have you added all the unnecessary `swal()` logic? I assume you've copied/pasted this from another answer?

Comment: I added example how I did, this is code from my project not copy/past from another answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use in your MVC view in ajax success-

```js
success:function()
{
window.localtion.href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")";
}
```

Comment: The OP is returning the URL from the AJAX request, not hard-coding it.

Comment: there is no need to go this way .he can simply send a string from controller and then redirect using hard coded way !@Rory McCrossan

Comment: Of course there's a need, for example if the page to redirect to is determined by the result of the logic executed on the server.

Comment: No need .sending a string on logic success may do all . @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Then your logic is spread between the server side and the client side. It make more sense to just send the URL in the response.

Comment: Sending as json also spreaded between server and client side .Nothing will happen without going to client side i think ! @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: You're missing the point, but I'm done explaining it. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Ok, Best of luck to you too @RoryMcCrossan